# Sound delay when using DTS Interactive

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, audio

I have ASUS Maximus hero VII motherboard with Realtek built in audio connected to a LG 5.1 DVD device with 5.1 speaker configuration using optical cable(S/PDIF).

All effects equalizers etc. are disabled from the audio settings on the PC. 
On the PC: if I use "default format" 16bits, 48000Hz (DVD Quality) everything is ok. The problem comes when I select default format: DTS Interactive (5.1 Surround) - there is sound delay of around 0.5s on every sound that comes from the PC including windows "ding" sounds, movies and even volume control.

I want to use DTS Interactive to play DTS audio tracks and movies with 5.1 sound but the delay is too long.

I am using Windows 8.1 with latest drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem stems from the fact that the 5.1 audio needs to be encoded on the fly in order to pass it over optical. This introduces delay (aka lag or latency). SPDIF is meant for two-channel and DTS is a method to get the 5.1 streams across a 2-channel wire.

**Movies** and 5.1 audio tracks **are pre-encoded 5.1**.

If you want to use it to watch movies (e.g. not games where the latency matters), there should be a setting for "**pass through mode**." This option has moved around a lot depending on the driver and manufacturer revisions.

You may need to also enable pass through in your movie player(s). **Sometimes it is called "bitstream" or "RAW."** I have a set-top device which calls it "HDMI RAW," and my TV calls it something else too. Basically, every piece of hardware between the source and the output need to be set to pass-through.

For games and real-time applications, this won't help. Many PC games don't support surround unless it is configured via the analog outputs however.

Comment: I can't find "pass through mode" or anything similar. I guess I should move to plan B and get a long HDMI cable...